# Better way to check variable for null or empty string? 

Tags: php, validation

Since PHP is a dynamic language what's the best way of checking to see if a provided field is empty?

I want to ensure that:

1. null is considered an empty string
2. a white space only string is considered empty
3. that "0" is not considered empty

This is what I've got so far:

```
$question = trim($_POST['question']);

if ("" === "$question") {
    // Handle error here
}
```

There must be a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: I would say to use empty($question), but that also considers 0 to be empty.

Comment: yoda conditions are horrid

Comment: I wish I knew a code that is *simpler* than just a basic condition.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

A literal answer to the question from the post title is quite obvious and straightforward:

```
function IsNullOrEmptyString($str){
    return ($str === null || trim($str) === '');
}
```

But for *input variables,* which you're actually asking about, it would be both superfluous and insufficient.

A `$_POST` array element cannot be null, hence checking for null would be superfluous. At the same time, any outside variable can be absent, which will raise an error and you probably want to avoid it. Therefore, given you need a `$question` variable, the code would be

```
$question = trim($_POST['question'] ?? '');
if ("" === $question) {
    // Handle error here
}
```

Comment: Since OP is asking for a 'simpler' version of an extremely simple operation, I'm going to say that 'better' is what's actually warranted.

Comment: I turned it into a function. this should make your validation code simpler

Comment: Using a function is the best way to simplify this, I do the same exact thing

Comment: what is the purpose of !isset() here? how is it different to is_null()?

Comment: also return (!empty($question) || trim($question)==='');

Comment: @nickf They're identical in this case. `is_null()` would error when passed an undeclared variable but a function argument is always declared. `!isset()` made more sense in the original answer, which wasn't a function.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: No, because `empty` considers zero to be empty, and OP specifies that `0` NOT be considered empty. If one *knew* that the input was a string, then you almost have a valid approach, except you forgot to remove the `!` -- should be `empty` rather than `!empty`.

Comment: BTW, experimenting I discovered that `trim(null)` and `trim($a)` where $a has not been declared, both return empty string, so the function can be simplified to `return trim($question==='');`

Comment: @SpYk3HH more experiments that show using empty is fraught with possibilities for mistakes.  `empty("0")` returns `true`.  `empty(" 0")` returns `false`. How many people know these subtleties? Using `empty` can lead to subtle errors; I would avoid it.

Comment: and if the input is an array?

Comment: It checks if the array is null or empty!

Comment: Quick nitpick, doesn't PHP use camel_case? Why use PascalCase for this function?

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment (misplaced right parenthesis): can simply do `return trim($question)==='';`

Answer (score 127):

Old post but someone might need it as I did ;)

```
if (strlen($str) == 0){
do what ever
}
```

replace `$str` with your variable.
`NULL` and `""` both return 0 when using `strlen`.

Comment: And there's always: `if(strcmp('', $var) == 0)...`

Comment: Why ==0 and not just if (strlen($str)) ?

Comment: @Noumenon Because that would impair readability without solving anything. It is real easy to read your suggestion as "if there is a length" while it (of course) means the opposite.

Comment: Will not help for string with spaces only, if someone cares for that

Comment: If the variable is not set, this will produce a warning

Comment: Would be nice to add trim between strlen and $str to remove whitespaces too.

Comment: If you have `declare(strict_types=1);` enabled, you you will get an error if $var is null. You must either do `$var === null || strlen($var) === 0`, or use `empty($var)`

Comment: @DanMorphis - except you **should not use `empty()`** for the situation requested by OP, as that will be incorrect for strings such as `'0'` and `'0.0'` (will be `false`, but OP wants `true` for strings that contain content).

Answer (score 31):

Use PHP's empty() function. The following things are considered to be empty

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

For more details check [empty function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Poster said that they DON'T want to consider "0" empty

Comment: @dougd_in_nc The purpose of SO is that questions are meant to be as generic as possible to build a knowledge base, and there are much more people - like myself - coming into this question from Google who don't have all of the original poster's requirements. For those people, this is the right answer and doesn't deserve the downvotes it has.

Answer (score 22):

I'll humbly accept if I'm wrong, but I tested on my own end and found that the following  works for testing both string(0) "" and NULL valued variables:

```
if ( $question ) {
  // Handle success here
}
```

Which could also be reversed to test for success as such:

```
if ( !$question ) {
  // Handle error here
}
```

Comment: may I suggest "if (trim($n)).." otherwise if a $_POST var (for example) is simply "   ", it would be considered valid, whereas, in most cases this is as good as an empty string

Comment: If " " is not an acceptable value for a specific function, then using trim would be a great idea.

Comment: This will return false for "0", numeric 0 or 0.0, and FALSE.

Answer (score 7):

Beware false negatives from the `trim()` function — it performs a cast-to-string before trimming, and thus will return e.g. "Array" if you pass it an empty array.  That may not be an issue, depending on how you process your data, but with the code you supply, a field named `question[]` could be supplied in the POST data and appear to be a non-empty string.  Instead, I would suggest:

```
$question = $_POST['question'];

if (!is_string || ($question = trim($question))) {
    // Handle error here
}

// If $question was a string, it will have been trimmed by this point
```

Comment: Id say if you get an array where you expected a string it should be an error. If you expect an array then you should have a separate filtering function for that.

Comment: Isn't that code treating it as an error?  If filtering is done elsewhere, care would have to be taken that it's not duplicating knowledge of the args' validation rules into separate places.

Answer (score 5):

In 2023 I'd recommend using the null coalescing operator. This will also supress an error in the case that the array key does not exist.

```
if (trim($_POST['question'] ?? '') === '') {
    // Handle error here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no better way but since it's an operation you usually do quite often, you'd better automatize the process.

Most frameworks offer a way to make arguments parsing an easy task. You can build you own object for that. Quick and dirty example :

```
class Request
{

    // This is the spirit but you may want to make that cleaner :-)
    function get($key, $default=null, $from=null)
    {
         if ($from) :
             if (isset(${'_'.$from}[$key]));
                return sanitize(${'_'.strtoupper($from)}[$key]); // didn't test that but it should work
         else
             if isset($_REQUEST[$key])
                return sanitize($_REQUEST[$key]);

         return $default;
    }

    // basics. Enforce it with filters according to your needs
    function sanitize($data)
    {
          return addslashes(trim($data));
    }

    // your rules here
    function isEmptyString($data)
    {
        return (trim($data) === "" or $data === null);
    }


    function exists($key) {}

    function setFlash($name, $value) {}

    [...]

}

$request = new Request();
$question= $request->get('question', '', 'post');
print $request->isEmptyString($question);
```

Symfony use that kind of sugar massively.

But you are talking about more than that, with your "// Handle error here
". You are mixing 2 jobs : getting the data and processing it. This is not the same at all.

There are other mechanisms you can use to validate data. Again, frameworks can show you best pratices.

Create objects that represent the data of your form, then attach processses and fall back to it. It sounds far more work that hacking a quick PHP script (and it is the first time), but it's reusable, flexible, and much less error prone since form validation with usual PHP tends to quickly become spaguetti code.

Comment: You did the exact opposite of what he wanted... simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

This one checks arrays *and* strings:

```
function is_set($val) {
  if(is_array($val)) return !empty($val);

  return strlen(trim($val)) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Not bad. The answer by PHPst does the same but more concisely though.

Answer (score 2):

to be more robust (tabulation, return…), I define:

```
function is_not_empty_string($str) {
    if (is_string($str) && trim($str, " \t\n\r\0") !== '')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// code to test
$values = array(false, true, null, 'abc', '23', 23, '23.5', 23.5, '', ' ', '0', 0);
foreach ($values as $value) {
    var_export($value);
    if (is_not_empty_string($value)) 
        print(" is a none empty string!\n");
    else
        print(" is not a string or is an empty string\n");
}
```

sources:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1):

empty() used to work for this, but the behavior of empty() has changed several times. As always, the php docs are always the best source for exact behavior and the comments on those pages usually provide a good history of the changes over time. If you want to check for a lack of object properties, a very defensive method at the moment is:

```
if (is_object($theObject) && (count(get_object_vars($theObject)) > 0)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to check if a value is provided for a field, that field may be a `string` , an `array`, or undifined.  So, the following is enough

```
function isSet($param)
{
    return (is_array($param) && count($param)) || trim($param) !== '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
// check for null or empty
if (empty($var)) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```