# Checking POST Value Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This is what I am using to check if an post value is empty or not in codeigniter.

```
if($this->input->post('inputEmail')) {  }
```

Just wanted to know what is the best method to check it, the above mentioned method or

```
$temp = $this->input->post('inputEmail');
if(!empty($temp)) { }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if variable empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777591/check-if-variable-empty)

Comment: The first one is best from my view.

Comment: once go through this [link](https://zainal.wordpress.com/2006/04/25/8/) and you can yourself take this decision

Answer (score -1):

Check with isset in php to check whether variable is set or not.

Try this:

```
if(isset($tmp))
{
    //it is set
}

else
{
    //not set
}
```