# Detecting if a variable is empty

Tags: php

I have a variable of $message that when I echo displays nothing. Unfortunately the following code does not work.

```
if (!$message) {
    echo 'Nothing here!';
}
```

When I `var_dump($message);` I get the following:

> string(48) ""

So it looks like somethings in there. Any ides?

Thanks,

John

Comment: So the string has a length of 48, is empty? How do you define `$message`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use :

```
if($var == "")
{
    echo("nothing here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `empty()`

`isset()` will return `true` for empty value

[What's the difference between 'isset()' and '!empty()' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

use one of these:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

```
if(isset($message)){
   echo "variable has value set";
}

if(!empty($message)){ 
   echo "Variable is empty";
}
```

Comment: You have a slight logical error, `!empty()` means that it's not empty ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!$message || $message == "") {
   echo 'Nothing here!';
}
```

You can also use `isset($message)` or `empty($message)`.

Comment: Or you can simplify it to `if (empty($message))`

Answer (score 0):

When you are typing the name of your question, notice, that below many same questions could appear, like in this post, and you will not duplicate it then. For example, first post where you can find many answers:
[check if variable empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777591/check-if-variable-empty)

And you save your time for typing question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I worked it out. I was building the $message variable with a load of MySQL queries and if there we're results displaying the in a table. I had a few  tags outside of a `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <> 0) { }` clause so they we're being saved in the variable.

Thanks all for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<?php
    is_null($var) //returns true if it's null

    empty($var) //returns true if it's empty

    isset($var) //returns true if it's not null.
?>
```

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

I hope I've helped!