# how to check if object's variable is not empty?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know if I correctly formulated the question. However, I've got 2 tables - products and categories (many to many relationship) and in categories page I want to display it's products with pagination if it has any and if it doesn't - I want to display "products not found". It worked, but without pagination.

Here's the controller:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($slug);
    $paginate = $category->products()->paginate(6);

    return view('site.pages.category')->with(['category' => $category,
    'paginate' => $paginate]);
}
```

What to do achieve this?

Comment: Use `!empty($var);` or `isset($var);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if variable empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777591/check-if-variable-empty)

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? undefined AKA `null`, empty string `""` or white-space string `"  "` ?

Comment: @JustinE 

I modified the controller like this:

public function show($slug)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($slug);
    $products = $category->products();

    if(isset($products) && !empty($products)){
    $paginate = $products->paginate(6);
    return view('site.pages.category')->with(['category' => $category,
    'paginate' => $paginate]);
    }
    else {
        return view('site.pages.category', compact('category'));
    }
}

However, now I get this: Call to a member function products() on null..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it around an if statement like `if(isset($your_variable) && !empty($your_variable)){` You may only need isset OR !empty, but you can mess around and see what works. Hope that helps!

Comment: I modified the controller like this:

public function show($slug)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($slug);
    $products = $category->products();

    if(isset($products) && !empty($products)){
    $paginate = $products->paginate(6);
    return view('site.pages.category')->with(['category' => $category,
    'paginate' => $paginate]);
    }
    else {
        return view('site.pages.category', compact('category'));
    }
}

However, now I get this: Call to a member function products() on null..

Answer (score 0):

I modified the controller like this:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($slug);
    $products = $category->products();

    if(isset($products) && !empty($products)){
    $paginate = $products->paginate(6);
    return view('site.pages.category')->with(['category' => $category,
    'paginate' => $paginate]);
    }
    else {
        return view('site.pages.category', compact('category'));
    }
}
```

However, now I get this: Call to a member function products() on null..

Comment: `$category` must be null here.

Comment: @JustinE same error when changed to $category. I don't think that $category should be null.. I want to display both categories who have products and categories that don't.

Comment: @VargVIkernes Just Debug through everyline. First, use `dd($category);` after the line `$category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($slug);`. You won't be getting an object here. That's why you are getting the error `Call to a member function products() on null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. I am not a Laravel Developer but just looked at some docs and writing this answer.

You are getting `Call to a member function products() on null` error, because `$category` is null (Not have any data). So you should check whether the `$category` have any data before calling `products()`.

And you can check whether the `products` is empty or not in blade template and print the message accordingly. No need to render another template for that.

```php
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($slug);

    if ($category) {
        $products = $category->products()->paginate(6);
    }

    return view('site.pages.category')->with(['products' => $products]);
}
```

And in your Blade Template, check the `$products` is not empty,

```php
@if ($products)
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        {{ $product->name}}
    @endforeach
    {{ $products->links() }}
@else
    products not found
@endif
```

And obviously, change the template to your needs.