# PHP / MySql : Show image A if field is NULL or 0, show image B if field is 1

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a php table showing tick and cross images based on 0 or 1 in a mysql table but the cross will not show the cross image if the value in the table is 'null'
Help please:

```
echo "<td>";
                                         
if($row['basic_site_induction']=="0")
{
echo '<img src="crosssm.jpg">';
}

else if 
($row['basic_site_induction']=="NULL")
{
echo '<img src="crosssm.jpg">';
}

else
{
echo '<img src="ticksm.jpg">';
}
                                     
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if variable empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777591/check-if-variable-empty)

Comment: No Sorry this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Why ? Can you dump `$row['basic_site_induction']`

Comment: The row 'basic_site_induction' is the row i need to show either 'NULL' '1' or '0'
Based on this 
'1' shows a tick image
'null' should show a cross image (But shows a tick)
'0' shows a cross image

Comment: Do a var_dump and show the result

Comment: I am really sorry, i am knew to php / mysql so just trying to find my feet. I have no idea what a var_dump is.

Comment: `var_dump($row['basic_site_induction']);`

Comment: You should also check is_null function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: So i should use ?

echo "<td>";

var_dump($row['basic_site_induction']);
                                            
if(=="1")
{
echo '<img src="ticksm.jpg">';
}

else
{
echo '<img src="cross.jpg">';
}
          
echo "</td>";

Comment: You can put it at the beginning or at the end, doesn't matter

Comment: i am sorry this doesn't work (sad face)

Comment: What do you get ?

Comment: I just get a blank page now

Comment: You need to enable error

Comment: I have just added the fields as 'hidden' on the submission form and set the value to 0 so it populates the database with a zero value and used my original php code. It seems a long way round but this now works. 
Thank you for your support.