# sporadic unwanted null entries in database $_GET

Tags: php, sql, ajax, sqlite, null

I have a little temperature protocoling web app, where degrees get adjusted on a page and saved in a database.

It works, but sometimes sporadic errors occur from users which I can't reproduce!

**Sometimes there are null-entries in the database and I don't know how and why. It "nulls" the hole row (several temperatures per day are selectable).**

If e.g. no temp got selected in a div string "NA" should be handed to the db. This bug is so resilient, I don't know where else to turn to.

*Ajax increases Values by clicking on Arrow*

```
$(".arrow_up").die('click');        
$(".arrow_up").live('click',function() {
    var value = $("#temp_"+this.id).html();
    if (value=="NA") {value=$("#istemp_"+this.id).html()}
            var newValue = parseInt(value)+ 1;
```

*hands Values over to server*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#save').die('click');                       
$("#save").live('click',function() {
    var tempA=$("#temp_itemA").html();
    var tempB=$("#temp_itemB").html();
```

*PHP has to store it*

I look if it isn't empty nor that the string null gets handed over. Last one throws Error.

```
<?php
    if((!isset($_GET['tempA'])) || (!isset($_GET['tempB'])) || ($_GET['tempA']!='null')
      {
        echo "values are missing";
      }
    else 
    {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:/var/www/xxx.sqlite');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $date=date("Y-m-d",time());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableTemp WHERE date='".$date."'";    
    $result = $dbh->query($sql);
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
    }

    if (!empty($id)) {
        $sql = "UPDATE tableTemp SET tempA='".$_GET['tempA']."',tempB='".$_GET['tempB']"'";
        $result = $dbh->query($sql);
    }

    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tableTemp ('tempA','tempB')";
        $result = $dbh->query($sql)
?>
```

I mean, this is as simple as it gets. I can only imagine the trasmitting errors might have something to do with WIFI and packet loss.

**How can I can stop inserting (discarding) these pesky null string into the db and throw an error, so that the user has to try it again? My !isset does not work since it isn't empty**

Comment: You could create a log file somewhere, and write the details of each SQL statement to it, as they're added - it might give you an idea as to where the rogue entries are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this is probably stating the obvious

But can you not stipulate that the column in the DB requires a value that is not null then catch the error on the insert

have you seen this answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103256/1479565

Comment: I thought my "if((!isset($_GET['tempA']))" does ask for non-empty valus? 

So you suggest alternativly "if((!empty($_GET['tempA']))"?

Comment: i generally do if(isset($val) && !empty($val)) that way you check that the variable is instansiated and has a value.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. I will implement it your way and see if the bug returns - still no idea though how this null-value appears.

Comment: i cant see where its coming from, but you can stop it from being inserted by using the not null param on the column, that way you will get an error message you can handle.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO tableTemp 'a', 'b', 'date') VALUES ('".$_GET['tempA']") CASE NOTNULL"; you mean like this?

Comment: i mean on the table creation specify the column as being not null

Comment: sry, the tables already exists. I just want to avoid saving/inserting null values in it. (sry for being complicated)

Comment: ah i got you have you tried the is_null function in php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php ?

Comment: no! amazing how many possiblities exist just to be sure that null does not slip by :) I'll try that.

Comment: unfortunatly it isn't null as in empty value, but null as a string gets handed over. I am working on logging.

Comment: I erred it isn't empty it is a string, how can I discard null-Strings before inserting?

Comment: count the length of it to make sure its > 0

Comment: not elegant but null as a string has 4 digits and the temps only max 3, so this could work out.
Although I don't know why ($_GET['tempA']!='null') doesn't work.

Comment: so the value NULL is in the string?

Comment: exactly, this came as a surprise. Since my logfile still fails me, I can't be sure from where. 

`function errorlog($text) {
    $date=date("d.m.Y",time());
    $entry=$date.": ".$text."\n";
    $dateiname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."log/errorlog.txt";
    $handler = fOpen($dateiname , "a+");    
    fWrite($handler , $entry);
    fClose($handler);
}
`
But `(strlen($_GET['tempA']<3)))` makes sense!

Comment: did you see the link i appended onto my answer?

Comment: Well, strlen<3 doesn't throw an error as with !='null'. But since it isn't the empty null, but instead the string null, it suffices

But why null comes from ajax as a string (seldomly) is unclear - Now I will implement logging, which still doesn't work.

Important thing is, user gets forced to try input again and sees an error.

Comment: ill have a think and see if i can suggest anything. Thanks Nicholas