# PHP own logfile function to check values and variables in routines

Tags: php, logging

I am still after this [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211127/sporadic-unwanted-null-entries-in-database-get), but now I am stuck (second day) with a logfile function.

```
function errorlog($text) {
    $datelog=date("d.m.Y",time());
    $entry=$datelog.": ".$text."\n";
    $filename= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."../../log/errorlog.txt";
    $handler = fopen($filename , "a+") or die ("can't open file"); 
    fwrite($handler , $entry);
    fclose($handler);
  }
```

**It doesn't get loaded with a syntax T_String exception, which I can't find at all.**
I know it's lame, to bother you guys with such cheap mistakes, but here I am.

it resides in an function.ini and should get called like this:

```
  errorlog("Pre-IF: ".$_GET['tempA']);
```

Comment: Can you show us which line gives you the error?

Comment: Can't find any error in this function. Can you be more specific and clear on which line the error is coming. What is the error message correctly saying.

Comment: sry guys, it is the $entry.. line 3

Comment: @Sabari btw. when I put line 3 under line 5 ($handler) it raises T_Variable for this line 5.

Comment: You might want to show more than what you're posting up here, there's no error in the code you're showing.

Comment: @Duniyadnd there isn't more unfortunatly. No matter where I paste this function, it raises Parse error: syntax error, unexprected T_Variable in line 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
function errorlog($text) {
  $date=date("d.m.Y - H:m:s",time());
  $entry=$date.": ".$text."\n";
  $dateiname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."log/errorlog.txt";
  $handler = fOpen($dateiname , "a+");   
  fWrite($handler , $entry);
  fClose($handler);
 }
```

well, it seems H:m:s was missing and the path was faulty: document root is /var/www/.