# Writing a PHP if Blank statement

Tags: php, variables

I'm new to PHP so this will sound basic to most people but I need to write the code for when a variable returns nothing (blank).

My variable is `$winner`, but sometimes there is no winner, in this case it just leaves the page blank, I would like it so if there is no winner then it will display "no winner".

This is my attempt:

```
if empty($winner) {
    echo "no winner";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381265/better-way-to-check-variable-for-null-or-empty-string

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to check the variable's valaue with null or empty...

```
function IsEmptyString($Season){
    return (!isset($Season) || trim($Season)==='');
}
```

This function can be used to check the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
if (!$winner) { // will catch "", null
    echo "no winner"
}
```