# Search Query Problems

Tags: php, mysql

A little help guys?

when i input list and slist the query works.
but if i only input list only it doesnt show the query for finding datas with category = list, same goes for the slist if i input slist only it doesn't show the query for finding datas with subcategory = slist.

for example if i input Toys on list and boy on slist the query executes and shows the products thats category = Toys and subcategory = boys
but if i only input toys in list and i didnt input anything on slist it doesnt shows the query for products that only shows toys the same thing happens if i only input slist

it only works if i input them both.. i need to make a search bar that can search for both, list only and slist only. 
Sorry for my bad english.

```
<?php
$category = $user_data['categoryquery'];

        $per_page = 15;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if($_POST['list'] != '' && $_POST['slist'] != '')
            $list = $_POST['list'];
            $slist = $_POST['slist'];
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$list' AND subcategory = '$slist' ORDER BY date_added");

            }else{
            if($_POST['list'] == '' && $_POST['slist'] != '')
            {
                $slist = $_POST['slist'];
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE subcategory = '$slist' ORDER BY date_added");
            }else{
            if($_POST['list'] != '' && $_POST['slist'] == '')
            {
                $list = $_POST['list'];
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$list' ORDER BY date_added");
            }else{
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: I would indent all of the code, and add { } to all of my if/else statements, to better follow the logic of the code.

Comment: Are you sure you have all of your **{** paired with **}**? Shouldn't there be a { following `if($_POST['list'] != '' && $_POST['slist'] != '')`?

Comment: i tried adding the { and } there but the $result near the end of the script won't work and a lot of errors appeared
i'll try to edit my indention  sorry bout that

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a `{` there `if($_POST['list'] != '' && $_POST['slist'] != '') ****HERE****`

correct this and fix your indents, it will help a lot

Comment: When i Added the { and } several errors appeared and it didn't show the $result near the end of the script i posted when i reloaded the Browser

Answer (score 0):

Can't run php right now to test this, but when you only input one of the POST variables, the other may be coming up as a null value instead of an empty string.

If that's the case, refer to the simple fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381265/better-way-to-check-variable-for-null-or-empty-string).