# If the file is in a BIM 360 or ACC workspace, how to view it in the browser

Tags: php, viewer

The document https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/ said:

If the file is in a BIM 360 or ACC workspace, the SVF/SVF2 file is automatically generated.
but I don't  know how to do.

I used  the api

```
    https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items/:item_id
    
    Obtained file details:
    ......
            ["storage"] => array(2) {
              ["data"] => array(2) {
                ["type"] => string(7) "objects"
                    ["id"] => string(81) "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.emea.2/8310b164-80ba-4837-bc4c-434626dae124.pdf"
              }
              ["meta"] => array(1) {
                ["link"] => array(1) {
                  ["href"] => string(186) "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.emea.2/objects/8310b164-80ba-4837-bc4c-434626dae124.pdf?scopes=b360project.0ba0f51f-b130-427a-b8cb-4a013982f81c,O2tenant.22909090"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

then use the following interface（

```
$urn is the return from the above: $result["included"][0]["relationships"]["storage"]["data"]['id']
```

）sent the request：

```
          // Step 2 - Check the Status of the translation job
            public static function checktranslationJob($AccessToken, $urn) 
            {  
                $urn = base64_encode($urn);
        // halt($urn);
                $url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/$urn/manifest";
        
                $signedurl = Session::get("signedurl");
               
                $head = [
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $AccessToken,
                ];
               
                $result = self::curlsent($url, '', $head, $method='get');
                return $result;
            }
```

Results can only be returned  "null"

What will I do?

Additionally, I have done this job by Uploading Source File to OSS:

```
// STask 3, Option 2 – Translate to SVF2
    public static function translateSvf2($AccessToken, $urn, $region) 
    {  
        // 以下是测试数据：
        // $urn = 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mo34_cheng_emea3/2731-00-10-01A.dwg';
        // $region = 'EMEA';
        // 
        // 下面是通过您的  uploadToBucket($AccessToken, $bucket_key, $object_key, $path_to_upload) 返回的数据：
        // array(3) {
        //   ["status"] => int(200)
        //   ["header"] => string(367) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        // Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Accept-Encoding, Range, Content-Type
        // Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
        // Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        // Content-Type: application/json
        // Date: Thu, 06 Jul 2023 02:55:18 GMT
        // Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
        // x-ads-region: EMEA
        // Content-Length: 304
        // Connection: keep-alive
        // "
        //   ["body"] => string(304) "{"bucketKey":"mo34_cheng_emea3","objectId":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mo34_cheng_emea3/2731-00-10-01A.dwg","objectKey":"2731-00-10-01A.dwg","size":4773732,"contentType":"application/octet-stream","location":"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mo34_cheng_emea3/objects/2731-00-10-01A.dwg"}"
        // }


        //下面是通过  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets?region=EMEA 得到的bucket详细信息：
        // array(5) {
        //   ["bucketKey"] => string(16) "mo34_cheng_emea3"
        //   ["bucketOwner"] => string(32) "ZAjD4dwoHF3h3PcAiXKsB8r8BGFYQZ9t"
        //   ["createdDate"] => int(1688427749021)
        //   ["permissions"] => array(1) {
        //     [0] => array(2) {
        //       ["authId"] => string(32) "ZAjD4dwoHF3h3PcAiXKsB8r8BGFYQZ9t"
        //       ["access"] => string(4) "full"
        //     }
        //   }
        //   ["policyKey"] => string(10) "persistent"
        // }

        $path_parts = pathinfo($urn);
        $filename_without_extension = $path_parts['filename'];

        $body = array(
            "input" => array(
                "urn" => base64_encode($urn),
                "rootFilename" => $filename_without_extension . ".iam",
                "compressedUrn" => true
            ),
            "output" => array(
                "destination" => array(
                    "region" => $region
                ),
                "formats" =>array(
                    array(
                        "type" =>"svf2",
                        "views" =>array(
                            "2d",
                            "3d"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

       // us
        // $url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job";
        // EMEA
        $url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/regions/eu/designdata/job";
       $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $AccessToken, 
                "x-ads-force: true"
            ],
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl); 
halt($response);//返回  bool(false)



        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: How do you expect people to help you if didn't provide the definition of `curlsent`?

Answer (score 0):

For files stored on BIM360/ACC, you don't need to request a translation by the current design. Please find `derivative` in the version in your first step instead.

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/versions/:version_id
    
    Obtained file details:
    ......
            ["derivative"] => array(2) {
              ["data"] => array(2) {
                ["type"] => string(7) "objects"
                    ["id"] => string(81) "...."
              }
```

Comment: Thank you . Through your guidance, the problem has been resolved!